# Entity Framework Select Row

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For some reason I can't seem to figure out how to use Entity Framework to select a single row.

Here is what I have:

Database: `ItemSchema` contains `Defindex`, `Name`, `MarketPrice`

I need to select the `Name` based on a `Defindex` I already have.

So I want to match the `Defindex` with a record, and retrieve the Name from that record.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549141%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534956%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if there should be no more than one row matching your Defindex value) to get single row from table:

```
var row = context.TableName.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Defindex == value);
if (row != null)
    // use row.Name;
```

If you are using default EF provider for SQL Server, then this will generate SQL query

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Defindex] AS [Defindex], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[MarketPrice] AS [MarketPrice]
    FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [DefIndex].[Id] > @value
```

Same query can be written also this way

```
var row = context.TableName.Where(r => r.Defindex == value)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

`SingleOrDefault` will try to select top 2 results and it will throw exception if there is more than one row returned.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. What is the r => for? That seems to be what got me caught up.

Comment: @Coffman34 that is [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx) which is converted into [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx) when you are working with Queryable type (i.e. querying database). Linq to Entities builds SQL query based on expression tree you are passing to it

Answer (score 0):

```
var defIndex=3; //your value
var item=yourDbContext.ItemSchemas.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.DefIndex==defIndex);
if(item!=null)
{
  //Record exists.Let's read the Name property value
   string theName=item.Name;
   // do something with theName now
}
```

Assuming your DBContext object has a collection(of ItemSchema) named `ItemSchemas`